# What exactly is a Full-stack development in Spring Boot with Java?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was under the impression that Angular is integrated as a front-end in the same project as Spring to avail beautiful looking websites as I did once in a previous project in a company.

But as I started looking some videos on youtube and udemy, they are creating a separate project for both angular and spring running on different ports 4200 and 8080.

Is this what a full-stack development is and is this what the companies are asking for in the interviews nowadays? Sorry if the question seems from 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, each of them is an ecosystem that communicates with each other via nowadays mostly rest.
Each of the code is compiled separately also, typescript and java.
As for full-stack requirements for job its most of the time on one side you have for an example spring boot microservice that does some logic and exposes those results on specific URLs, and you consume those results with your frontend and display them accordingly.
Now, when it comes to frontend you can simply mock values and do your development instead of waiting for someone to finish their backend and after they are done you just write it to the specification that they provide. Most of the time its used Open API ( ex Swagger ).
But basically if you call yourself fullstack developer you need to be able to write backend that emits responses with some results, and write frontend that consumes those responses and displays them. Front side of an application as well as back side.
There are approaches where you use only JS ( nodejs for backend, react or angular for frontend and mongodb for database ), but if you end up in some company where are old-school people, it will be Java on backend and they are looking for youngsters that are Jedi Knights in JS, at least that is what my company did a month ago.

Comment: Am I not a full stack developer even if I know Jsp, thymeleaf, velocity, etc?

Comment: jsp and thymeleaf is not that widely spread in the industry, most of the time its angular, react or vue. As for velocity, that is used for email templating. For an example, you want emails to be structured to your standards. Velocity is not required in fullstack arsenal BUT! as in all companies everything is more than welcome to know.